# jquery knob updating by javascript from a webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, jquery-knob

I want to use the jquery knob to show values parsed from a webservice, updating every 1 seceond. In the code below, the webservice url will return 60 (tested ok) but I cant figure out how to update the knob.

(I have the script for drawing the knob running, but left it out for simplicity here)

My code:

```
   <script>
    function updateknob() {
        var $s = $(".load"),
             s = d.load('webservice.php?type=dummy'

        $s.val(s).trigger("change");
        setTimeout("updateknob()", 1000);
    }
    updateknob();
    </script>
    <div class="demo" style="width:100%">

        <div style="width: 30%; border: 3px ; margin-bottom: 20px">

            <input class="knob second" data-width="20%" value="35">
        </div>
    </div>
```